# Angularjs refresh ng:view

Tags: refresh, angularjs

While using Angularjs v0.9 and php to implement my membership system

In this following function, I will call an api to edit the data of the member, on success, the php function will return

```
{"success":"true"}
```

and the controller will return to a page that can view the member of the data.

```
if(response.success==="true") {
window.location="#/register_members";
$('.alert-error').hide();
$('.alert-success').html("Member is updated.");
$('.alert-success').fadeIn();
}
```

However, at #/register_members, the data still remains as the unchanged data. Is there anyway I can refresh the page partially in angularjs? I am using ng:view and $route.

I have tried using

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

but the success message will not be rendered as the whole page is renewed.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: One question: Why are u still using 0.9? I would rely on the location service of Angular which works fine for me in every case. Second thing, why do you use jQuery to update the dom within the controller? You can just use two-way binding and update the variable. Or did I got something wrong?

Comment: the php API function will update the database and will return a response. So i am working with the response. :) it was an old project with v0.9. just taking out to try other stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an interesting answer [here](http://ved-antani.com/2010/12/jquery-refresh-a-div-inside-the-same-page/) to refresh a div in the page using Jquery

my page is "#/register_members"
the div i want to update is "#registerlist" which is inside a div called "#browse-box".

so now my controller will be

```
window.location="#/register_members";
$("#browse-box").load("/#/register_members #registerlist")
$('.alert-error').hide();
$('.alert-success').html("Member is updated.");
$('.alert-success').fadeIn();
```

works like a charm. :)